# How to set multiple environments in zf2

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, configuration, zend-framework2

So for i was using this, in `.htaccess`

```
SetEnv APP_ENV development
```

and than i `config's` files

```
 $env = getenv('APP_ENV');
if($env == 'development'){
//do something
}else{
//someting else
}
```

but things are getting uglier now, as there are multiple environments:

1. Development
2. Testing
3. Production
4. Server 1
5. Server 2

and for each environment there are different `database settings` and other settings
so is there a better solution than changing the `.htaccess` file everywhere??

Comment: `config/autoload/local.php` should contain your environment-specific settings, and this file should be different in each environment. That is the standard approach in ZF2 - is that not suitable?

Comment: @TimFountain my solution  talk about that. Indeed.

Comment: Who the fu** down vote that ..

Answer (score 2):

I can propose you my architecture :

We not use `.htaccess` but virtual hosting and define in our virtual host , e.g :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory c:/wamp/www>
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

From here what I have in my configuration :

```
// application.config.php
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            sprintf('config/autoload/{,*.}{global,%s,local}.php', $env),
        ),
```

where `$env` equal to :

```
$env = getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') ?: 'development';
```

And for your config/autoload/ files depends on your env you have (examples) :

**Production :**

- orm.production.php

**Preproduction :**

- orm.preproduction.php

**Development**

- orm.development.php

**Testing**

- orm.testing.php

Where orm is your database configuration. (I use doctrine)

And in `doctrine.global.php`, when I want to load the environment params for database config I have this :

```
//doctrine.global.php
    'doctrine' => array(
        'connection' => array(
          'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' =>'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => include "orm.{$env}.php",
          ),
        ),
```

Make sure those files are not versionned with your git/mercurial/anythingelse (ignored files)

And then you are good to go.